# I can't import BeautifulSoup from bs4 (pip has installed Beautiful Soup4)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to create a web scraper. I've installed BeautifulSoup4 in my terminal with the command:

```
pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

When I check and see if it has installed successfully, my terminal tells me "Requirement already satisfied" which means yes.

I open Visual Studio Code and type:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
```

I get an error.

> Error = from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ModuleNotFoundError: No module
> named 'bs4'

Since BeautifulSoup4 is installed I expected no issues in importing. Please help me solve this error.

Comment: Pip installs are per python installation. Do you have more than one python installation? Does VSC refer to the same version as your terminal?

Comment: Verify that VSCode is using the interpreter which `pip` is packaged with. Or, figure out which interpreter VSCode is using and install with `python -m pip install BeautifulSoup4`, where `python` is the path to the interpreter.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks for the help. Fixed the issue by installing 'virtualenv', trying the pip install again, which gave me a successfully installed message instead of request satisfied. I then installed 'requests' and reloaded VSCode. The error cleared after that.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Thanks for the help! Cleared the error!